# undefined reference in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, pango

I was installing ImageMagick in ubuntu,by mistake i installed the default 16 bit quantum depth version, but i needed the 8 bit version,so i unintsalled the 16 bit version using `make uninstall` from the source folder then i configured the 8-bit using `./configure --with-quantum-depth=8` the installed it.

now i am getting these error, while building my project.

`` /usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `FcWeightToOpenTypeDouble' ``

`` /usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined reference to `FcWeightFromOpenTypeDouble' ``

before uninstalling the build was successful but after uninstalling and reinstalling again,building the project fails for any quantum depth configuration and shows the above error.

Help appreciated,thank you,

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235716

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMake...

Answer (score 2):

When you run `make install` it checks all the code is correctly compiled and linked and then installs (i.e. copies) the binaries (`magick`, `convert`, `animate`, `compose`, `mogrify`, `montage` etc)  into `/usr/local/bin` or wherever you configured.

When you do `make uninstall` it removes those binaries from `/usr/local/bin` but doesn't clean up the directory where you compiled/built the binaries.

TLDR; You need to run:

```
make clean                           # clean up build area
./configure --with-quantum-depth=8   # set your desired configuration
make -j4                             # rebuild (in parallel)
make install                         # copy to /usr/local/bin
```